# Matplotlib not installing inside virtualenv mac

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, virtualenv

So I have Python 3 and `matplotlib` installed globally. If I run python outside of a virtual environment and import matplotlib to check the version it shows 1.5.1 . But I am facing problems installing matplotlib within a virtual environment. I created a virtual environment using the command `python3 -m venv ds` and activated `ds`. These are the contents of my `requirements.txt`

`matplotlib==1.4.2
numpy==1.9.1`

When I do `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` I get this

```
    Collecting matplotlib==1.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached matplotlib-1.4.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/ym/gfrm424x31j4vd944cdhn4hr0000gn/T/pip-build-pcfq8bhb/matplotlib/setup.py", line 155, in <module>
        result = package.check()
      File "/private/var/folders/ym/gfrm424x31j4vd944cdhn4hr0000gn/T/pip-build-pcfq8bhb/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 962, in check
        min_version='2.3', version=version)
      File "/private/var/folders/ym/gfrm424x31j4vd944cdhn4hr0000gn/T/pip-build-pcfq8bhb/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 446, in _check_for_pkg_config
        if (not is_min_version(version, min_version)):
      File "/private/var/folders/ym/gfrm424x31j4vd944cdhn4hr0000gn/T/pip-build-pcfq8bhb/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 174, in is_min_version
        return found_version >= expected_version
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/version.py", line 70, in __ge__
        c = self._cmp(other)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/version.py", line 337, in _cmp
        if self.version < other.version:
    TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.4.2]
                    python: yes [3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015,
                            21:12:44)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot
                            3)]]
                  platform: yes [darwin]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.10.4]
                       six: yes [using six version 1.10.0]
                  dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                            axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                      pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                            it after matplotlib.]
                   tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                            WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                 pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                            mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                     pycxx: yes [Official versions of PyCXX are not compatible
                            with matplotlib on Python 3.x, since they lack
                            support for the buffer object.  Using local copy]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ym/gfrm424x31j4vd944cdhn4hr0000gn/T/pip-build-pcfq8bhb/matplotlib
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How should I install matplotlib version 1.4.2 in virtual environment ?

My question has been marked as duplicate but that link doesn't solve my question. The solution given is for Ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib compilation error: TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024731/matplotlib-compilation-error-typeerror-unorderable-types-str-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it by solving the dependencies for matplotlib, 
(if you have `brew` installed)
then first do `brew install freetype` followed by `brew install ttfautohint --with-qt`. After that try again to pip install.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system package in your virtualenv with [this](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#the-system-site-packages-option) option.

Otherwise, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024731/matplotlib-compilation-error-typeerror-unorderable-types-str-int) may help you.

Comment: how to install libfreetype6-dev on mac ?

Comment: Yeah if we have brew, we can do brew instal freetype

Comment: Besides, you managed to install matplotlib globally. The steps for installing it in your virtualenv are the same.

Comment: There you go - that's one answer. Here're some more: http://www.freetype.org/ttfautohint/osx.html